# JS Regex to match a start and end pattern plus contain square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Sample input string

```
"Hi ${spurs.stadium[capacity]}" to return "${spurs.stadium[capacity]}"
"Hi ${spurs.stadium}" to return ""
"Hi ${spurs.stadium{capacity}}" to return ""
```

So I am looking for pattern where

1. string starts with `"${spurs."`
2. string must contain after this square brackets which can have any content
3. end with `"}"`

I have tried `const regex = /[$]{spurs.+?[}]/gi` but it doesn't require the square brackets it seems optional. Any ideas?

Comment: `/\${spurs.stadium\[{1}.*\]{1}}/gi` ?

Comment: Would `\$\{spurs(\.\w+)+\[.*?\]\}` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match by order of appearance. Left to right.

EDIT: added a lazy (not greedy) quantifier `?`

```js
var str = "Hi ${spurs.stadium[capacity]} dog" // to return "${spurs.stadium[capacity]}"
var str2 = "Hi ${spurs.stadium}" // to return ""
var str3 = "Hi ${spurs.stadium{capacity}}" // to return ""
var str4 = "Hi ${spurs.stadium[capacity]} ${spurs.stadium[crowd]}";

const regex = /\${spurs\..*?\[.*?\]}/gi

console.log(str.match(regex));
console.log(str2.match(regex));
console.log(str3.match(regex));
console.log(str4.match(regex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

`\${spurs.*\[(.*)\]\}`

1. `\$` - literal dollar
2. `spurs.*\[` - spurs and any character after until opening square
   bracket
3. `(.*)\]` - any character until closing square bracket (saved in a
   capture group for extraction later, if needed
4. `\}` - closing bracket

Here is a [working example](https://regex101.com/r/OToNCS/1):

Comment: One edge case I found test.

if it happens twice in a string I want it to be able to parse out each individually

"Hi ${spurs.stadium[capacity]} ${spurs.stadium[crowd]}" to return "${spurs.stadium[capacity]} and ${spurs.stadium[crowd]}". Right now its returning as a single match.

Comment: StevieB, that means you don't use the [g]lobal modifier.

Comment: @stevieB so just change it to be lazy regex with `?`: `\${spurs.*?\[(.*?)\]\}`. Here is the [working version](https://regex101.com/r/AZSq8Y/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution which uses the `match()` method(more info on [it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)):

```
const paragraph = '"Hi ${spurs.stadium[capacity]}" to return "${spurs.stadium[capacity]}" "Hi ${spurs.stadium}" to return "" "Hi ${spurs.stadium{capacity}}" to return ""';

const regex = /{.*?}/g;

const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
```